# Paginated Report-Date Parameter Range

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I am using Paginated Reports against a dataset published in the cloud.  I click on Query Designer to drag all the columns to the page and build my query parameters (i.e, not report parameters). When I add my date parameter, I have options in the dropdown of 'equal to', 'not equal to', 'contains', 'begins with.', 'range(inclusive)', 'ange(exclusive)', and 'Custom'.  I want the date parameter such that when the user selects a date in the parameter prompt, the query returns 13 months of data, ending on the date they select in the parameter, so if they select 10/31/22, the results will be 10/31/21 thru 10/31/22. I don't want the user to have to enter a start and end date range if I don't have to.  Given the parametr options I have, I don't see how to do this.  I thought about modifying the code of the resulting query statement (it begins with EVALUATESUMMARIZECOLUMNS). I see logic in the code that says 'RCustomDaxFilter(@Date,EqualtoCondition'.  I thought about changing the 'EqualtoCondition' to something like 'Between', but nothing works.  Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

This request is a bit old but leaving here an answer maybe will help others.

In the query designer you could use the following expression:

```
> EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
>     'table'[field1],
>     'table'[field2],
>     'table'[START_DT], 
>     'table'[END_DT],
>      FILTER(
>      VALUES('table'[END_DT]), 
>       @date_selector <= 'table'[END_DT]
>     ),
>     FILTER(
>      VALUES('table'[START_DT]), 
>       @date_selector >= 'table'[START_DT]
>     )
>     ) ORDER BY 
>     'table'[field1] ASC
```

Of course you need to customize it if you dont want the parameter.
Mind you that these are query parameters.
more details on types of paginated report param [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-dataset-filters-data-region-filters-and-group-filters?view=sql-server-ver16).